# Starting a State in Lex from Yacc

Tags: c, state, yacc, lex

In Lex i can start a new state using the keyword BEGIN STATE1. I want to do the same from yacc in between rules . In the action section of a rule , if i add BEGIN STATE1 , it says BEGIN undeclared error. Is there any way i can do this?

Comment: I suppose
[this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379930/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-flex-start-state-from-bison)
and its answer will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ise Wisteria found the answer for me.

Create separate functions in lex that use the BEGIN macro . Call them in bison .

Note:For those very beginners like me , do not forget to add a declaration of these functions at the beginning of the .y file or you will get an undeclared error during linking.